# How can I have two applications installed in Android with the same code base

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am trying to have two applications with the same code base. Why that? Because I am using Crashlytics and I must have the main application installed and the beta application installed as well. Because the testes want to compare both applications "in a good way" such as open the beta application and click on home button and open the main application and compare anything.

I have created a buildType like this...

```
buildTypes {
        Debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        beta {
             debuggable false
             signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
             ext.enableCrashlytics = true
             applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
    }
```

}

but when I build my application using Beta or Bebug buildTypes just replace my application installed and does not create one more application.

I have changed my `applicationIdSuffix` for `".beta"` and my main application has `applicationId "com.br.whatelse.application"`.

Is it possible I have two applications installed with the same codebase?

Comment: "And a productFlavors like that" -- that is not supported by the current generation of build tools, as you need a flavor dimension. Plus, you need 2+ flavors. The simplest solution is to get rid of the flavors (unless you need them for other reasons) and move your `applicationIdSuffix` to the `beta` build type.

Comment: @CommonsWare Cool man. Do you have some link for helping me?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html#change_the_application_id_for_build_variants

Comment: I have tried this way as I said but when I build that just replace my application installed and does not install a second.

Comment: Please explain how you "build that". Are you using Android Studio? If so, did you choose the build variant that has the desired suffix?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry about that. My English is rusty. I am using Android Studio and choosing Build variant. I have killed the productFlavors because I think it is unnecessary since I can set the IdSuffix and NameSuffix inside beta build type. When I build using build variant as beta() and build again as debug() two applications are not installed. The first build updates the second. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I mean the second build updates the first.